# How to create ipa in xcode 6 without Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode6, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution, apple-id

Need to generate `.ipa` file for Ad-Hoc distribution. Client has provided only certificates, private keys and provisioning profiles which were enough to create `.ipa` till Xcode 5. But in Xcode 6.1 when I export as `Save For Ad Hoc Deployment` it gives message

```
To save for Ad Hoc Deployment, you need to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program for the development team 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

[image]
[image]

Is there any way of creating `.ipa` without developer account credentials?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Finally found a way for creating `.ipa` build with [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) command.

1. Right click on `Archive` on Organizer.
2. Click `Show in Finder`.
3. You can see `.xcarchive` file in Finder.
   [image]
4. Open `Terminal` and `cd` to `.xcarchive` path.
5. Using following command to generate `.ipa` file.

This will save `.ipa` on Desktop.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath <FILE_NAME>.xcarchive -exportPath ~/Desktop/<FILE_NAME>.ipa
```

Still looking for better solution, don't know why Apple removed this feature from Xcode 6 :(

Comment: I would like to copy .xcarchive after Step 3 and paste it on desktop and in step 4 Open Terminal and cd to desktop instead to a long file path :P

Comment: Will this also sign the build with proper provisioning and certificate?

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing using Xcode 6.1 but my IPA wont install on device. I figured out the solution that you need to specify your provisioning profile name using "-exportProvisioningProfile <PROVISIONING PROFILE NAME>" option in the above command.

Comment: @PankajRathor what is the value of <PROVISIONING PROFILE NAME>.  Is it my name that shows up under "Team" in the "General" --> Identity tab in Xcode app settings?

Comment: Will this work for iOS App Store Deployment? I have same issue but i need to create .ipa to upload it on app store.

Comment: @ABJ I'm getting 'exportPath' doesn't exist

Comment: what if there is no archive option is enable?

Comment: This answer is probably obsolete now.

Comment: invalid option '-exportFormat'

Comment: I am getting: "`error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.MyApp' were found`" with Recovery-Suggestion: "`Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'com.MyApp'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.`" and adding `-allowProvisioningUpdates` option just changes message to `Team "MyTeam" does not have permission to create "iOS App Store" provisioning profiles.`

Answer (score 57):

There are **3 WAYS** to create .ipa **WITHOUT** *Command & Apple Developer Account*.

**1. Fast & Best**

*(Works on all Xcode, All Mac OS, Bundled package can be used for OTA links like [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/))*

1. Just build `(Command+B)` your app from XCode by setting proper code signing identities
2. From `XCode's` file search at left bottom, search for `.app` (This will be under product directory)
3. Right Click on this `.app` file and select ***Show in Finder***
4. Now, create directory and name it as **Payload**, copy `.app` into Payload directory.
5. Archive/Compress(.zip) this Payload directory, rename file extension from .zip to .ipa

---

**2. Extract .ipa from organizer**

*(Works on all Xcode, All Mac OS)*

1. Create Archive
2. Go to Organizer
3. Get location of Archive by ***Right Click*** and selecting ***Show in Finder***

[image]

4. Now right click on this .xcarchive file and select ***Show Package Contents***
5. Go to path `Products > Applications > YourAppFile`
6. Open iTunes's on Mac and drag-drop this  *YourAppFile* from above path in **Apps** tab. (NOTE: Delete the previous app with the same identifier if any)
7. Now right click on your app under **Apps** tab of iTunes and select **Show in Finder**, this is your .ipa file !!!

---

**3. For devs having Xcode 5.x**

*(**NOTE:** Xcode 5.x doesn’t work on El Capitan, By this way you can archive using any Xcode but you will need Xcode 5.x to create .ipa)*

1. Create Archive using any Xcode version.
2. Close Xcode.
3. Go to Organizer window of Xcode 5.x and from Archive tab select your archive.
4. On top right section select `Export`, click radio button with title `Save for Ad Hoc Deployment`
5. Click `Next` and Select desired code signing identities to save .ipa

Comment: hello. this ipa file cant not install in iphone

Comment: been using these methods for years :-) check if you are using correct profiles

Comment: 2nd method works for xcode 8.3.2. 1st one doesn't work.

Comment: Is a FREE `Apple ID` a proper `code signing identity`?

Comment: @AdityaDeshmane after creating ipa i need to enroll my developer account and add device uuid?

Answer (score 20):

You can also create an IPA file using Xcode 6 & latest follow below steps:

1. Create Build File of your Project `Command+B`
2. Go to Products folder & it will show app file right click "Show In Finder".
3. Create an empty folder & call it 'Payload' then copy your app file in that folder.
4. Archive Payload Folder & rename the zip file to `YourApp.ipa`

Comment: The best, fast and easy solution!!
Just to clarify this answer in more details :

Create Payload empty folder -> Create one empty folder and name it as 'Payload'.

Comment: @DaxeshPatel how do I get to this "Products" folder?

Comment: Found out that Products folder is in the root of the folder that you get to using left click and "show package contents".  BTW, This solution works..thanks.

Comment: @SmartHome yes, you are right. Though It will be right click.

Comment: This working for me in Xcode 7.2 to run an app on an iOS 9.3 device.  Note: "Archive" in this context simply means (right click) "compress."

Comment: Has anyone got this working recently? The comments are from 2016

Answer (score 3):

There is even better way without doing all the command line stuff.

Select "Save For Ad Hoc Deployment" & Click Next.
Then open the "select a development team" drop down. It will have the option "Use Local singing assets" at the bottom. Select this option & Click Choose.

Here you go. The build will be created by Xcode without Apple ID Account.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately that option is not available in Xcode 6. It is only available in Xcode 7.

Comment: Where is this "Save for Ad Hoc Development" option in xCode 7?

Comment: @JungleJim, please have a look in the question's graphics attached.

Comment: @AsifBilal Thanks but I can't figure out how to get to that screen in the first place without a developer account. When I go to [Product][Archive] with an iOs device hooked up, it just says "Build Failed". Same thing with a Generic iOs device. When I do the build for an emulator, the build succeeds but when I click on [Product] then [Archive] is faded and can't be selected. Or am I going to the wrong place to get to that "Organizer - Archives" screen in the first place?

Comment: @JungleJim, When you go to [Product][Archive] with an iOS device, try to find out the reason why it throws the "Build Failed" error. Once you find out the reason, resolve it. And do the preceding steps to build ipa file.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use Xcode 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

From some time (for example Swift & Xcode7) when you are to make a build formula is more complicated - xcodebuild requires exportOptionsPlist parameter:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist app.plist  -archivePath app.xcarchive -exportPath app.ipa
```

and app.plist contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Getting: "`error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.MyApp' were found`" with Recovery-Suggestion: "`Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'com.MyApp'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.`"

Comment: Adding `-allowProvisioningUpdates` option just changes the output to: `Team "MyTeam" does not have permission to create "iOS App Store" provisioning profiles.`

Comment: still no answer regarding this solution?