# My iOS app works in simulator but instantly crashes when I try to open it on my phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

[EDIT] Possible fix: my ipa was unsigned, I bought a Developer's account and will test tomorrow with a signed .ipa. [/EDIT] This is my second app. It's very simple, all it does is send a post request to my server, and display a response. It works perfectly on the iOS simulator on Xcode, but when I push the ipa to my phone, it just crashes. A friend of mine also tested it, and the same happened. Can you please take a look at the code? 
It's not that long:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByoF_XNJWlVyeHJHdHp3LVdTS3c/view?usp=sharing
Here's the ipa:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByoF_XNJWlVyeGJrNldMb1BPMVE/view

I also can't/don't know how to get a crash report for the app on my phone, so if you need that I'd need help on how to get it too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your phone is connected to the internet before making post request and you have submitted build not code that i am not able to check your code

Comment: Well I just ran the project on my device and its working absolutely fine. Its asking to put in some code to proceed.

Comment: What you can do is to make a breakpoint on all exceptions, and while debugging, check where the code breaks. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LPKMV.png. Also do a clean build.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala can you tell me on which device/iOS version? Thanks!

Comment: **iPhone 5** - **iOS 8.1.2**

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala Thanks. Did you build the .ipa from the xcode project yourself or installed the one I provided? I don't have a developer account, so the built ipa is unsigned. Could that have any effect? If you built it yourself, can you upload the .ipa so I can test it on my device?

Comment: No, I ran the project from Xcode to my device. Let me see if I can upload the .ipa

Comment: To find the crash report, connect your device to your mac, go to **xcode > devices > (select a device) > View Device Logs**

Answer (score 1):

[image]It would be helpful if you could paste the crash report, you can connect your device and debug it for the same.

Possibility is : You might have built your app using **iOS SDK 8.0** or above and trying to run it on a lower version. 
Also, to make it compatible with your device you need to avoid using methods that are introduced in iOS8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wrote the app using XCode 5.1, the deployment target is 7.1, and the base SDK is also 7.1. I'm testing it on iPhone 6+ 8.1.1. On my phone, under Settings - Privacy - Diagnostics & Usage - Data - I can't find a crash report for the RealCode app...

Comment: I just downloaded your app and installed it on my device. You need to change the Code Signing from Developer to Distribution.
Just check it for your Target in Build Settings --> Code Signing. Check the screenshot in the updated answer

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't have a Developer account, therefore I can't sign the app :/ But I guess that's the problem, then. Is it too much to ask if you could upload the signed .ipa for me to test?

Comment: I would have done that if I had my own account :). But Since I am using my organization's Dev Account, I am not authorized to do so. 
At least you know the solution now :)

Comment: Follow These steps to create an ipa.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account) and den upload it to (http://www.diawi.com/#), you will get a link. open that link in ur device's browser.

Comment: Yes, I've just bought my account, it should be live tomorrow. I'll check if everything works once it's signed, and update this post with an answer. Thanks once again!

Comment: Yes, I thought I've added the solution... My bad. Buying the account fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you make post request to check if the internet is connected or not ..

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
if (data){
    [self yourPostMethod];
}

else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Network not Reachable" message:@"Please check your internet connection!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];
}
```

Comment: To view the source please download the zip file on the first link, and it should be on RealCode/RealCode/RCViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you have developed app using Xcode 5.1 and deployment target to 7.1 .
If you want to make sure it should work onlatest versions, you need to update your xcode and set base sdk to latest and deployment target you can set 7.0

Comment: I can't upgrade xcode because I'm not on Yosemite and my update fails for some reason. This is on a hackintosh too... but I'll keep trying to update, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Buying a Developer Account fixed my problem.