# How To make iPA File without Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

is there any way to create iPA file without developer account and without use distribution certificate.

Comment: You might be ale to create it, but it would be useless since you can't install it on any device.

Comment: as per my knowledge you won't be able do it.

Comment: I don't think so, without developer account, you can't create an IPA.

Comment: Thanks for the reply rck,is there any way how to create build without using certificate.

Comment: I think free developer account still can make IPA, not so sure

Comment: Look at this one and see if that helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account

Comment: You can build you app, but you need to sign it, for this part you will need a provisioning profile.  the ipa is just a zip containing al the files and you signed app.

Comment: @Nathasha i have already try this one link.but this is not working for me.

Comment: There is no other way without certificate to make ipa