# How to export ad-hoc .ipa from xcode project without apple developer account

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to export an ad-hoc ipa file from my xcode project but i do not have a developer account. I do have the exportOptions.plist file that is necessary for exporting ad-hoc. but i don't know how to do the rest.
so what should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ipa in xcode 6 without Apple Developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account)

Comment: @Md.MostafizurRahmanMafi the output in that case is enterprise. it is not ad-hoc

Comment: You need a developer account to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ad-Hoc builds require a Ad-Hoc provisioning profile. You can only get an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile from a paid Apple Developer account.

To answer your question:

**You should get a paid Apple Developer account**

Comment: thank you for your response. but the problem is i'm iranian and apple has sanctioned everything and i can not do that 

Comment: well that stinks. distributing your app in any way, shape or form requires an account. even certain functionality (like APNS) requires a paid account. maybe you might be able to use a proxy to get around sanction?

Comment: even if i do that. i would need a paypal account or visa card or master card to pay for it. and all of these things are sanctioned here.