# Is there a way to install an app for ios without downloading it from stores, or connecting it to a PC using a USB cable and using xcode?

Tags: ios

I developed an app for ios. I know how to do the process to install it on an ios device using xcode. I currently have a free ios account, the "apple id" has not purchased the license to publish in stores (my client will not pay any account to publish)

The problem is that I live in Colombia and my client lives in Mexico. Under these conditions I don't know what I can do so that my client can test the application on his ios device. something like testfligth (but if I'm not bad, I must have the developer license).

What can I do under these conditions?

I summarize them:
1- I don't have a developer account (I don't have money to pay for it), that's why I can't publish in stores or use testflight.
2- I cannot connect my client's ios device to my pc, because we are in different countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three main ways to install an app on an iOS device:

1 - Locally with a mac and Xcode, using USB.

2 - Via Apple Store and TestFlight, but this requires a paid $99 developer account

3 - Via Ad-Hoc outside the Apple Store, but this requires a certified company and a paid $299 enterprise account.

You could go to the [jailbreak route](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82902), but I do not recommend it in this case. It would be complicated, your client would also need a jailbroken device and it could lead to unexpected errors.

You can send him the entire source code and ask him to install himself, but I think would be risky as he could just not pay you.

So the best solution would be to not install on his device.

I would schedule a remote access session and let him play on your local simulator.

Comment: to install the application on an ipad using xcode, can I do it with my apple id? (I don't have a developer license)

Comment: Yes, it would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without distribution signing certificates, you can generate `.ipa`, [ways to achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account), and use 3rd-party software to install application on device.

Comment: 3rd-party shuch as which? do you know?

Comment: Some that I came across as mentions are https://www.diawi.com/ and Cydia Impactor. Haven't tried any, so can't vouch for either though.