# How to create an IPA without having Developer Account in IOS in react-native in Updated OS and Xcode?

Tags: ios, react-native

We have created the .xcarchive file code signing with our client's certificate & distribution provisioning profile, but we need to send the .ipa file to our client so that they can upload the app to the App store using Application Loader.

The only way to create the .ipa file in Xcode 4.5 is clicking Distribute -> Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment which has a description underneath saying "Sign and package application for distribution outside of the iOS App Store".

If we save the .ipa file this way, will it cause any problem submitting to the app store? Or is there a proper way of converting the .xcarchive to .ipa?

I want to create an IPA, but i don't have a Developer Account . but i want to share IPA to Client but i don't want to purchase any subscription!!
Any Solutions ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account

This explains it quite well.  As long as you have the distribution / provisioning profile of the client - there shouldn't be any issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a Provisioning Profile in Xcode then below method will 100% work as it works for me :

Step:1  Create Archive

Step:2 Right-Click on the Archive and Click Show in Finder.

Step:3 You can see .xcarchive file in Finder.

Step:4 Right CLick on the .xcarchive file and click `Show package content` and go to the `Products -> Applications` folder. Create a new folder named `Payload` and drag the .app file into that folder.

Step:5 Compress [Create Zip File] the Payload folder and rename it to whatever you want and change the extention to .ipa.

Step:6 Upload that .ipa file in Diawi website and share it with Client.

Comment: It works  Correctly !!!

Comment: @Jagroop It seems that although I could configure my ipa file, it doesn’t pass the Firebase app distribution

Comment: I could get a Firebase app distribution with this trick, however when I try to open the app from my iPhone, it says "Unable to install App. Please try again later". So I assume something is missing/wrong with that distribution.

Comment: I get the following error.
"This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified"